# Can i automate product version with script file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, build-automation

I want to automate process of updating version number. i'm maintaining version number in one const string variable in .cs file. In my .cs file i have other variables too.

How do i iterate through file to find string variables value and then update it with new value??

Comment: `.cs`? Isn't that C#, rather than vbs?

Answer (score 0):

.cs files are just plain text, so just use a `For` loop with `Set` string substitution.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (input.cs) do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:Find=Replace!"
        echo(!line!
)) > tmp.txt
Move /y tmp.txt input.cs
```